# androidでzip4jを使いパスワード付きzipファイルを展開したいが文字化けを起こす

Tags: java, android

androidでパスワード付きのzipファイルを展開するアプリを作っているのですが日本語名が含まれるzipファイルを解凍した際日本語の含まれるファイルが文字化けしてしまいます。

どのようにすれば文字化けぜずに解凍できるようになるのかヒントになりそうなことあれば教えていただきたいです。

```
import net.lingala.zip4j.core.ZipFile;
import net.lingala.zip4j.exception.ZipException;
import net.lingala.zip4j.model.UnzipParameters;


public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        try {
            String zipFilePath =Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath() + "/PassZip/日本語.zip";
            String destinationPath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath() + "/PassZip/";
            File dir = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath() + "/PassZip/");
            if (!dir.exists()) {
                dir.mkdir();
            }
            String password = "password";
            try {
                ZipFile zipFile = new ZipFile(zipFilePath);
                if (zipFile.isEncrypted()) {
                    zipFile.setFileNameCharset("csWindows31J")
                    zipFile.setPassword(password);
                }
                zipFile.extractAll(destinationPath);
            } catch (ZipException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }catch (Exception e){}
    }
}
```

Comment: `日本語.zip`の文字エンコードは`Windows-31J`でしょうか？

Comment: 日本語.zipの文字エンコードの調べ方がわからないのですが調べる方法を教えてほしいです。

Comment: zipの仕様書をちゃんと読んだわけではないのですが、圧縮されたzipが何のエンコードで符号化されているかを知る術はなかったと記憶しています。OS標準の機能で圧縮した場合、MacはzipファイルはUTF-8、WindowsはWindows-31Jであることが多くよくトラブルになるのです。

Comment: 日本語が含まれたzipファイルandroid上では文字化けしていませんが解凍した際、例えば日本語 123.pdfの場合数字とアルファベットと文字化けを起こしていませんが「日本語 」の部分のみ文字コードを変換していっても文字化けは治らないです。

Comment: ”「日本語 」の部分のみ文字コードを変換していっても"とは具体的にどういうことを指していますか？`zipFile.setFileNameCharset("csWindows31J")`に与える文字コード名を適切なものに変更すれば、解決するのではないかと思います（ここを自動識別するアーカイバソフトは、自前で文字コード判定を行っていることが多いみたいですね）。

Comment: https://teratail.com/questions/36274　マルチポスト

Answer (score 2):

以前、私がActionScriptでZipファイルを解凍するライブラリ(airxzip)を作ったときの事を参考に記述します。

まず、Zipのファイル名はUTF-8もしくは、Windows-31J(SJIS)です。
確かファイル名の文字コードに関しては、厳密な仕様はなかったと思います。

また、UTF-8がやっかいで、WindowsとMACで濁点などの考え方が違うのでこの当たりを制御しないと文字化けがおきます。
（MACで日本語がよく文字化けしている理由がそれです）

Javaではありませんが、以下のgetFilenameUTF8というメソッドがUTF-8のデコードをしている処理です。

https://github.com/coltware/airxzip/blob/master/airxzip/src/com/coltware/airxzip/ZipHeader.as

おおよそ、これで問題になったケースはなかったので大丈夫だとは思います。